# Why group by date is returning multiple rows for the same date?

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I have a query like the following.

```
select some_date_col, count(*) as cnt 
from <the table>
group by some_date_col
```

I get something like that at the output.

```
13-12-2021, 6
13-12-2021, 8
13-12-2021, 9
....
```

How is that possible? Here `some_date_col` is of type `Date`.

Comment: Because your date value actually has a time component.  Try performing this before your query: `ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MON-DD HH24:MI:SS';`

Comment: Check out this fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=4b6294949c93b54854a4163678fea375

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `DATE` is a binary data-type that is composed of 7 bytes (century, year-of-century, month, day, hour, minute and second) and will **always** have those components.

The user interface you use to access the database can choose to display some or all of those components of the binary representation of the `DATE`; however, regardless of whether or not they are **displayed** by the UI, all the components are always **stored** in the database and used in comparisons in queries.

When you `GROUP BY` a date data-type you aggregate values that have identical values down to an accuracy of a second (regardless of the accuracy the user interface).

So, if you have the data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE the_table (some_date_col) AS
SELECT DATE '2021-12-13' FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 6 UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2021-12-13' + INTERVAL '1' SECOND FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 8 UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2021-12-13' + INTERVAL '1' MINUTE FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 9;
```

Then the query:

```sql
SELECT TO_CHAR(some_date_col, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') AS some_date_col,
       count(*) as cnt 
FROM   the_table
GROUP BY some_date_col;
```

Will output:

> | SOME_DATE_COL | CNT |
> | --- | --- |
> | 2021-12-13 00:01:00 | 9 |
> | 2021-12-13 00:00:01 | 8 |
> | 2021-12-13 00:00:00 | 6 |

The values are grouped according to equal values (down to the maximum precision stored in the date).

---

If you want to `GROUP BY` dates with the same date component but any time component then use the `TRUNC`ate function (which returns a value with the same date component but the time component set to midnight):

```sql
SELECT TRUNC(some_date_col) AS some_date_col,
       count(*) as cnt 
FROM   <the table>
GROUP BY TRUNC(some_date_col)
```

Which, for the same data outputs:

> | SOME_DATE_COL | CNT |
> | --- | --- |
> | 13-DEC-21 | 23 |

And:

```sql
SELECT TO_CHAR(TRUNC(some_date_col), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') AS some_date_col,
       count(*) as cnt 
FROM   the_table
GROUP BY TRUNC(some_date_col)
```

Outputs:

> | SOME_DATE_COL | CNT |
> | --- | --- |
> | 2021-12-13 00:00:00 | 23 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=89ebbe8b8285276b604652ce83b4218a)*

Answer (score 1):

Oracle date type holds a date and time component.  If the time components do not match, grouping by that value will place the same date (with different times) in different groups:

[The fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=369b2b2c6dac3e9adcbc10d3f890fa2d)

```
CREATE TABLE test ( xdate date );

INSERT INTO test VALUES (current_date);
INSERT INTO test VALUES (current_date + INTERVAL '1' MINUTE);
```

With the default display format:

```
SELECT xdate, COUNT(*) FROM test GROUP BY xdate;
```

Result:

| XDATE | COUNT(*) |
| --- | --- |
| 13-DEC-21 | 1 |
| 13-DEC-21 | 1 |

Now alter the format and rerun:

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MON-DD HH24:MI:SS';

SELECT xdate, COUNT(*) FROM test GROUP BY xdate;
```

The result

| XDATE | COUNT(*) |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-DEC-13 23:29:36 | 1 |
| 2021-DEC-13 23:30:36 | 1 |

Also try this:

```
SELECT to_char(xdate, 'YYYY-MON-DD HH24:MI:SS') AS formatted FROM test;
```

Result:

| FORMATTED |
| --- |
| 2021-DEC-13 23:29:36 |
| 2021-DEC-13 23:30:36 |

and this:

```
SELECT to_char(xdate, 'YYYY-MON-DD HH24:MI:SS') AS formatted, COUNT(*) FROM test GROUP BY xdate;
```

Result:

| FORMATTED | COUNT(*) |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-DEC-13 23:29:36 | 1 |
| 2021-DEC-13 23:30:36 | 1 |

Comment: For me, this still didn't make any difference. What actually worked was to cast this date column to timestamp.

Comment: Could you create a test case, like the one I created, but which shows your specific problem?   Maybe you are controlling the format in a different way and continue to remove the time component from the output.  This `ALTER` only impacts the current session.

Comment: @MetallicPriest Also try the new `SELECT` I added to the end of the answer. This will produce the correct output, regardless of the session format setting.

Comment: @MetallicPriest `SELECT to_char(xdate, 'YYYY-MON-DD HH24:MI:SS') AS formatted, COUNT(*) FROM test GROUP BY xdate;`  See the updated answer and fiddle.

Comment: @MetallicPriest - if "cast[ing] this date column to timestamp" actually did work, then you did the casting wrong, too. If you do it correctly, it shouldn't help, since casting to timestamp does not change the time component. Of course, there was nothing that was supposed to "work" in Jon's answer, since he didn't tell you how to fix the problem, he only told you why you got those results that you thought were wrong. You only asked "how is that possible", you didn't ask "how do I fix it".

Comment: @MetallicPriest Just to be clear, your question was about explaining the result.  The solution, once you know the reason, is fairly obvious.  Remove the time component, which is done many ways.